# How to perform addition of address to get new address in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add an address to get a new address for an operation.
For e.g., As a result of adding A$10 and 2, I want a result of A$12

I appreciate if you can help me with the possible formulas

Comment: `OFFSET` may do what you want

Comment: or, `=INDEX(A:A,10+2)`

Comment: Thank you OFFSET works fine for my usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFFSET works fine for the above use case.

The OFFSET needs to be used as follows to return the address value

```
OFFSET(INDIRECT(A$10),2,0)
```